# iOS Pebble-Watch Launching & Killing "Self.connectedWatch"

Tags: ios, iphone, pebble-watch

When I read the sample code for Launching and killing your Pebble app:

```
[self.connectedWatch appMessagesLaunch:^(PBWatch *watch, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully launched app.");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error launching app - Error: %@", error);
    }
}
];
```

What that mean **Self**? How can I create something like self
in this code because I give the error the Property 'connectedWatch' not found on object of type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look in the .h file and add this property between `@interface` and `@end`, like so:

`@property (strong) PBWatch *connectedWatch;`